# ¿Que Lenguaje de Programacion recomendarian para tratar imagenes pixel por pixel?

Tags: imagen

Se trata de:
Procesamiento de imagenes digitales.
Pixel por Pixel.
Y busco recomendacion y quiza una pequeña nocion de algun lenguaje de programacion que pueda ayudar en el caso.

Comment: Mira por favor [ask]. Las preguntas sobre recomendaciones no son bien vistas en el sitio.

Comment: vale, soy nuevo en esto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitivamente Matlab, es una opción muy completa y robusta que ofrece gran cantidad de herramientas para procesamiento de imagenes sin tener que hacer mucho esfuerfzo

Estos son algunos links que te pueden servir de ayuda para empezar:
https://www.dc.uba.ar/materias/t1/2016/c1/archivos/2016/introimagenes

http://informatica.uv.es/iiguia/VC/tutorial.pdf

Comment: Hola Faruck, bienvenido.. mira por favor [tour] y [answer]. Las preguntas sobre recomendaciones no se deben contestar porque estan fuera del alcance del sitio.

Comment: Gracias, me sumergire en el mundo de la programacion y MatLab.

Comment: Cuando una respuesta te sirve, se acostumbra a marcarla como respondida.

Comment: de acuerdo, sigo novato en esta web, poco a poco aprendere, pero le di aspa verde a tu comentario.